# Google maps javascript v3 api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, compass-geolocation

How I can use google maps COMPASS mode for building web app?

Does it possible with google maps v3 or not?

Is this possible only with ANDROID api for maps?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps API supports special 45° imagery for certain locations. This high-resolution imagery provides perspective views towards each of the cardinal direction (North, South, East, West). These images are available at higher zoom levels for supported map types.

Any existing Pan control on a map will alter to add a compass wheel around the existing navigation controls. This compass allows you to change the heading of any 45° imagery by dragging the wheel, snapping the direction to the nearest supported direction which contains imagery.